# Discord.py AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute '_UnionGenericAlias'

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tracked my error to this code, which is in a cog:

```
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name="help")
async def help_slash(self, ctx, Command_Name=None):
    
  await helpMethod(ctx, Command_Name)
```

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 102, in <module>
    class bot(commands.Cog):
  File "main.py", line 110, in bot
    async def help_slash(self, ctx, Command_Name=None):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/cog_ext.py", line 63, in wrapper
    opts = manage_commands.generate_options(cmd, desc, connector)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/utils/manage_commands.py", line 313, in generate_options
    SlashCommandOptionType.from_type(param.annotation) or SlashCommandOptionType.STRING
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 488, in from_type
    and isinstance(t, typing._UnionGenericAlias)  # noqa
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute '_UnionGenericAlias'
```

My research suggests this may be an error with Python itself. If so, is there a way to circumvent the problem? I have tested helpMethod: the error comes from the declaration of the slash command.

Thanks so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Python 3.8 typing library code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/typing.py), you can see `_UnionGenericAlias` is not defined.
However, in [Python 3.9](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/typing.py), it is defined.
So the solution is you have to upgrade your Python version.